# Extract RDS address value using data external in terraform

Tags: terraform, shell-script

I am using data external block to extract the address of RDS

```
data "external" "rds_endpoint" {
  program = ["/bin/bash", "-c", "aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier blast-dev-postgres --region eu-west-1 | jq -r '.DBInstances[0].Endpoint.Address'"]
}
```

On CLI, this gives the address as output. However, the output of `data external` needs to be a json object. How to have this output as JSON?

Comment: can we see the output data and what `jq` is returning and what you are expecting?